# Developer Tools Keeps Popping up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have clean installed Chrome twice now but the problem persists.

The  Developer Toool opens up when i navigate any website. This is random. I close it and it opens again.

An indicative image of the issue is in Right Hand Side

[image]

I am on Chrome latest version (Version 44.0.2403.107 m)

There are various thread on Google but no definite solution yet.

Comment: Not sure but isn't it offtopic here and better suited for superuser.com?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Any bodya knows?